# Commonly ASM-written parts of a C++ program?

Tags: c++, assembly

Most C++ compilers allow you to inline ASM within the C++ code. Which parts of a C++ program are typical contenders for this ASM inlining? Are there particular parts of C++ which compilers still struggle to optimize?

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you have to ask, you neither need nor are able to use inline assembly ;-)

Comment: The optimization capabilities of modern compilers nowadays border on magic. *Very, very* rarely will you need to resort to inline assembly for optimizations. Usually it's done to invoke processor-specific instructions the compiler does not have built-in intrinsics for.

Comment: asm for optimization would probably hurt more than help even if you wrote the best possibly assembly within the block, anyway, since the compiler could give up doing any further analysis of code possibly affected by your assembly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Assembly Language in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202687/using-assembly-language-in-c-c)

Comment: @delnan thank you for your valuable contribution.... next?

Comment: Or anything that doesn't fit the procedural regime, like messing with the stackframe

Comment: @user997112 - There really *isn't* any parts that the compilers "struggle" with. The compiler writers also know all the tricks in the book and have implemented them in their compilers. I have [an example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11639305/597607) that shows how 10 lines of C++ templates are reduced to 4-5 machine instructions by the compiler. There just isn't anything you can improve on there, whatever you do.