# Unable to swap values

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, assembly

In the below code, output remains same in both cases,thanks for pointing what am I missing:-

```
Before Swap:-
a=10     b=512
After Swap:-
a=10     b=512
```

Following is the code, It compiles and runs without any problem:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int swap(int* x, int* y)
{
    if(x != y)
    {
        _asm
        {
            mov eax,[x]; x into eax
            mov ebx,[y]
            mov [x],ebx;swapping now
            mov [y],eax
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main () {
  int a=10,b=512;
  printf("Before Swap:- \na=%d\t b=%d\n",a,b);
  swap(&a,&b); 
  printf("After Swap:- \na=%d\t b=%d",a,b);//Value remains same
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `std::swap` in `<algorithm>`

Comment: Perhaps relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529778/reason-why-custom-loop-is-faster-bad-compiler-unsafe-custom-code-lucklucky

Comment: Checking for x != y probably costs more than just exchanging two identical values. If this is an exercise for learning assembly code, fine; but the compiler will do just as good a job as you can here (in fact, better -- there's an unneeded instruction in the assembly code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No indirection on variables inside assembly block wont work.Instead take addresses in registers and then only try indirection.It will rather break into something like `mov eax, DWORD PTR _x$[ebp]`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int swap(int* x, int* y)
{
    if(x != y)
    {
        _asm
        {
            mov eax,x
            mov ebx,y
            mov ecx,[ebx]
            xchg ecx,[eax]
            xchg [ebx],ecx
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main () {
  int a=10,b=512;
  printf("Before Swap:- \na=%d\t b=%d\n",a,b);
  swap(&a,&b);
  printf("After Swap:- \na=%d\t b=%d",a,b);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not wrong, but could you please not advocate `xchg` with a memory operand?

Comment: @harold:- long days gone,being with assembly. So just dropped the ash of burnt up knowledge with mere perfection. :)

Comment: swap without using third variable in c language : http://allitstuff.com/swap-without-using-third-variable-in-c-language/

Answer (score -3):

You can swap with Xor operation -

```
void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
     *x = *x ^ *y; /* #1 */
     *y = *x ^ *y; /* #2 */
     *x = *x ^ *y; /* #3 */
}
```

Comment: That destroys the value if both pointers are equal, and it is likely slower than a standard swap using a temporary variable.

Comment: The question wasn't how to swap, it was why the given assembly code isn't working. And XOR swap is worse than normal swap in almost every way.

Comment: 2 downvote ... at least now I know that this is not so good patent.

Comment: I gave it a 3rd down vote. Now if you delete it you get a badge. `<g>`