# Can we develop something that turns high-level languages into assembly code?

Tags: performance

I am new to programming, have been doing it on and off for a year, and only really understand python from a syntactic standpoint. Is there something out there that allows python or other high-level languages to be reformed into a lower-level language such as assembly? I understand that a language gets converted to lower-level language when ran but why can't we just run the code from an already lower level? Wouldn't this increased speed?

Overall I am just curious.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: As I know C++ can be compiled to assembly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138521/is-it-feasible-to-compile-python-to-machine-code

Comment: Numba can convert specialized Python code to LLVM-IR which can be converted to assembly (dynamically). Cython transform most Python codes to C then compiled to assembly (standard C compilers). Such processes are internally extremely complex for someone who just start programming.

Comment: As for writing code directly in assembly: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62981904) is a related question. Put it shortly, it is not always faster and it is not portable either.